# How can i find the keyboard in the device is default keyboard or not?

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, focus, scrollview

I have problem with dealing with the keyboards other than the default keyboards.

Am using this code to make my scroll view layout scroll to end completely.

```
scroller.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

This code is working fine for me, but in case of using some other keyboards in devices then the focus is lost from focused objects.

Do you have any solution to overcome this. Or do you know any code to identify the keyboard type.